# CSV Dataset extract and match data in columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-analysis

I have a dataset where I have airports 'type' and 'name' columns. What I want to do is from this data frame to create new data frame where I have 'small', 'medium' and 'large' airports and their belongings name. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

I have no idea what approach I should use. Anyone who could show me the direction. I do not know how to match the type of the airport with its name and then create a new table out of it. The outcome should look like something like this:

[image]

and so on.
Many thanks for any direction.

Comment: You should take a look at [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dummy DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "type": ["hellport", "small_airport", "large_airport", "medium_airport", "small_airport"],
        "name": ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name4", "name5"],
        "etc1": [1, 0, 1, 0, 2],
        "etc2": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    }
)
```

Print DataFrame

```
             type   name  etc1  etc2
0        hellport  name1     1     1
1   small_airport  name2     0     1
2   large_airport  name3     1     1
3  medium_airport  name4     0     1
4   small_airport  name5     2     2
```

What you want

```
df_group = df.groupby('type')['name'].unique().reset_index()
df_group = pd.concat([df_group, df_group['name'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1).set_index('type').drop(columns='name').T
```

Print df_group

```
type hellport large_airport medium_airport small_airport
0       name1         name3          name4         name2
1         NaN           NaN            NaN         name5
```